A dimensional analysis example in Barenblatt's book
I am reading "Scaling" by G.I. Barenblatt.
In Chapter 7 he presents an example I struggle to follow. He is looking at animals' breathing rate, and he goes:
"<..>
Our basic assumption is that the breathing rate of the animal, i.e. the ,ass $R$ of oxygen that it absorbs per unit time, is determined by the following quantities: the body mass $W$ of the animal, the density $\rho$ of its body and the specific absorptive capacity $\beta_n$ of its respiratory organs. Hence
$$R = f(W,\rho, \beta_n)$$
<...>"
where $n$ refers to the dimension  of the respiratory organ, whether a whysker, a surface or a solid.
Now, dimension-wise
$$ [R] = MT^{-1} $$
$$ [W] = M $$
$$ [\rho] = ML^{-3} $$
$$ [\beta_n] = ML^{-n}T^{-1} $$
From here, following the textbook one sees that there are 3 governing parameters (W, $\rho$, $\beta_n$), all with independent dimensions and could conclude straightforwardly that
$$ \frac{R}{\beta_n (W/ \rho)^{n/3}} = \it{constant}$$
The author instead makes a point, "<...> we note an important feature: the mass of oxygen absorbed and the body mass of the animal may be measured in independent units. <...> thus we choose the $LMTM_0$ class of systems <...>""
in which the governing parameters have units
$$ [R] = M_o T^{-1} $$
$$ [W] = M $$
$$ [\rho] = ML^{-3} $$
$$ [\beta_n] = M_{o} L^{-n}T^{-1} $$
In Chapter 5 (on Prandtl's boundary layer) he shows another example where the same nominal property is measured in different units and therein I see the point.
I fail to see why this would be necessary here.
Using $LMT$ or $LMTM_o$ as systems of units does not change the fact all three governing parameters $W, \rho, \beta_n$ have still independent units, and the final conclusion is the same.
Thanks for helping me to understand this.
